# Postgres seems to keep getting shutdown after a while

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql

I restart postgresql and then browse around in my app but then after a while it seems to shutdown and I get this message:

```
exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
file: "/root/maketube/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
line: 664
message: "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused↵  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting↵  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?↵could not connect to server: Connection refused↵   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting↵    TCP/IP connections on port 5432? (SQL: select * from "tags")"
```

I have it installed on my production server: psql (PostgreSQL) 10.7 (Ubuntu 10.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

My postgres log does not say much more:

```
2019-04-11 21:59:36.475 UTC [18074] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2019-04-11 21:59:36.475 UTC [18074] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2019-04-11 21:59:36.480 UTC [18074] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2019-04-11 21:59:36.513 UTC [18075] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-04-11 21:55:54 UTC
2019-04-11 21:59:36.776 UTC [18075] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-04-11 21:59:36.778 UTC [18075] LOG:  redo starts at 0/16BA7C8
2019-04-11 21:59:36.778 UTC [18075] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/16BA800: wanted 24, got 0
2019-04-11 21:59:36.778 UTC [18075] LOG:  redo done at 0/16BA7C8
2019-04-11 21:59:36.911 UTC [18074] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-04-11 21:59:37.459 UTC [18082] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Anyone know whats happening?